# jquery remove only effect the first span

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Refer to my jsfiddle , my jquery only work for the first "X" i click but not the second or third ?

2) how do i disable it when it only left one input ?

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/jfbQs/)

```
<div class="main-form">
    <fieldset id="ingt">
        <legend></legend>
        <div class="formheader">
            <label style="width:170px;"></label>
            <label></label>
        </div>
        <div class="formrow">
            <span class="drag"></span>
            <input type="text" max-length="30" name="recipe[ingredient][0][amount]" />
            <input type="text" id="ingredient" size="60px" name="recipe[ingredient][0][ingredient]" />
            <span id="remove">X</span>
        </div>
        <div class="formrow">
            <span class="drag"></span>
            <input type="text" max-length="30" name="recipe[ingredient][1][amount]" />
            <input type="text" id="ingredient" size="60px" name="recipe[ingredient][1][ingredient]" />
            <span id="remove">X</span>
        </div>
        <div class="formrow">
            <span class="drag"></span>
            <input type="text" max-length="30" name="recipe[ingredient][2][amount]" />
            <input type="text" id="ingredient" size="60px" name="recipe[ingredient][2][ingredient]" />
            <span id="remove">X</span>
        </div>
        <div id="add"></div>
        <button id="addi" type="button" onclick="add_field()">Add </button>
    </fieldset>
</div>

$(function () {
    $("#remove").click(function () {
        $(this).parent().remove();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

ID of an element must be unique, use class instead

```
<span class="remove">X</span>
```

then

```
$(function () {
    $(".remove").click(function () {
        $(this).parent().remove();
    });
});
```

The ID selector will return only the first element with the said element so your selector `$("#remove")` will return the first element with the the id `remove` so the click handler will get added to only that element

---

Also since you have an add button I'm assuming you will be adding dynamic elements, so use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) to handle the new elements

```
$(function () {
    //if you want to make the last item in the list(in terms of position) to non removable
    $(".main-form").on('click', '.remove:not(:last)', function () {
        $(this).parent().remove();
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/r33JS/)

or

```
$(function () {
    $(".main-form").on('click', '.remove', function () {
        //if you want to make the last item in the list to non removable
        if ($('.remove').length > 1) {
            $(this).parent().remove();
        }
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/wU49E/)

Comment: fantastic ! thanks ! but how do i restrict it to the last one is not clickable ?

Answer (score 1):

Duplicate IDs. ( IDS need to be unique )

```
<span id="remove">X</span>
```

change to

```
<span class="remove">X</span>
```

and change the script

```
$(".remove").click(
```

Answer (score 1):

Id should be `unique`. So you can use class instead of it.

Change `id='remove'` to `class='remove'`

and try,

```
$(function () {
$(".remove").click(function () {
      $(this).parent().remove();
    });});
```

To restrict last one not clickable, Just try,

```
$(function () {
$(".remove").click(function () {
      if($(".remove").length > 1){
         $(this).parent().remove();
      }
    });});
```

Comment: fantastic ! thanks ! but how do i restrict it to the last one is not clickable ?

Answer (score 1):

ID must be unique, I will suggest you to use class instead

```
$(".remove").click(function () {
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

HTML

```
<span id="remove">X</span>
```

change to

```
<span class="remove">X</span>
```

[Fiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mKYRz/1/)

Comment: fantastic ! thanks ! but how do i restrict it to the last one is not clickable ?